# Time in android,works in some cases, fails in other

Tags: android, datetime, simpledateformat, date-comparison

We can choose any time from a given slots . If the time choosen is 1 hour less than the current time then we have to show an alert. The below is what I have written. But its not fully correct.In some cases it works

```
    String Date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy").format(new Date());
    //to get current date
    String Time = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a").format(new Date());
    //to get current time

    String DeliveryDate=deliveryDate.getText().toString();

    if (Date.equals(DeliveryDate)) {
        //comparing current date and delivery date,delivery date choosen from calendar
        if (deliveryTimeText.compareTo(currentTime) < 3)
        {
             showToast("Sorry! Delivery Time is less by 1 hour. Cannot place order");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use [Calender](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Calendar.html) for complex date comparisons .

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends, and adding [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project in order to use `java.time`, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: What makes you think that `deliveryTimeText.compareTo(currentTime) < 3` would work? That certainly isn’t documented. Also please follow the naming conventions when asking us to read and understand your code. It’s particularly confusing that you’ve got a type named `Date` and a variable of a different type also named `Date`.

Comment: Could you [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), please? We don’t know the types of `deliveryDate`, `deliveryDate.getText()`, `deliveryTimeText` nor `currentTime`. Then it’s very hard to guess why your code only works sometimes. Also concrete examples of data with which it works and data with which it fails, and in what way it fails, are needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert your deliveryDateTime in `Date` class using `SimpleDateFormat`.
Ex.

```
try {
            if (currentDate.equals(DeliveryDate)) {
                String deliveryTime = "1:00 PM";
                SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(
                        "hh:mm a", Locale.ENGLISH);

                java.util.Date currentDate = simpleDateFormat.parse(deliveryTime);
                Calendar curDate= Calendar.getInstance();
                curDate.setTime(currentDate);
                Calendar currentDateDelivery= Calendar.getInstance();
                currentDateDelivery.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY,
                        curDate.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
                currentDateDelivery.set(Calendar.MINUTE,
                        curDate.get(Calendar.MINUTE));

                Calendar threeHoursLaterTime = Calendar.getInstance();
                threeHoursLaterTime.add(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 3);
                if (currentDateDelivery.getTimeInMillis() < threeHoursLaterTime
                        .getTimeInMillis()) {
                    showToast(
                            "Sorry! Delivery Time is less than 3 hours.Cannot place order");
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Now its showing the toast for every delivery time we select

Comment: @SRM yes you are correct but I have checked this with different inputs. so I am sure this code is working, please debug on your side.

Comment: yes. the code is right and it works..it was just a small error in my part